# Audit policy setting for cryptographic key operations

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm getting a ton of 5061 and 5058 entries on my 2008 R2 servers although the audit policy should be suppressing them. Why?

`auditpol /get /category:*` returns the following.

```
System
  ....
  Other System Events                     No Auditing
  ....
```

Based on my reading at [What's New in Windows Security Auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560628(v=ws.10).aspx) this should be the policy responsible for logging regarding 'Cryptography key file and migration operations'.

These events are from the `Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider` and all focus on opening and managing the keys so it really sounds like that should be covered by the audit policy defined here.

What am I missing? I'm positive that the tertiary "Force audit policy subcategory settings" is enabled - the registry key is correct.

Comment: I´ve seen a web debugging proxy (like Fiddler) generates a lot of 5061 and 5058 events when decrypt HTTPS traffic is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have an answer after a lot of searching.

Apparently this is under a different heading than it sounds like it should be one is 
[Audit System Integrity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd941605(v=ws.10).aspx) the other [Audit Other System Events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772739(v=ws.10).aspx).